# why this way return an instance of my object correctly, but this way does not

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm trying to create a small library, and I'm now in `event` method that add event to an element.
Now when use like the following code, return an instance of my library object correctly.

```
event: function (event, callback, sync) {
    var _this, len;
    _this = this;
    len = this.length;
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        if (len > 1) {
            while (len--) {
                this[len].addEventListener(event, callback, sync);
            }
        } else {
            this[0].addEventListener(event, callback, sync);
        }
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        if (this.length > 1) {
            while (this.length--) {
                this[this.length].attachEvent('on' + event, function () {
                    callback.call(window.event.srcElement);
                });
            }
        } else {
            this[0].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    }
    return this;
}
```

But when add a small code does not return an instance of my library object correctly, but return windows object.

```
event: function (event, callback, sync) {
    var _this, len;
    _this = this;
    len = this.length;
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        if (len > 1) {
            while (len--) {
                this[len].addEventListener(event, function (e) {   // <<-- From here
                    var e = e.target;   
                    _this[0] = e;
                    _this.length = 1;
                    callback();        
                }, sync);
                delete this[len];
            }                                                         // <<-- to here
        } else {
            this[0].addEventListener(event, callback, sync);
        }
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        if (this.length > 1) {
            while (this.length--) {
                this[this.length].attachEvent('on' + event, function () {
                    callback.call(window.event.srcElement);
                });
            }
        } else {
            this[0].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    }
    return this;
}
```

The problem in this part

```
this[len].addEventListener(event, function (e) {
    var e = e.target;
    _this[0] = e;
    _this.length = 1;
    callback();
}, sync);
delete this[len];
}
```

When use it

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"> 
    <span class="box"> span</span>
    <span class="box">span 2</span>
    <span class="box">span 3</span> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
oo('.box').event('click', function () {
    console.log(this); // this return the windows object not my library object.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
callback();
```

by

```
callback.call(_this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in a callback, out of scope.
If I am not wrong your variable is returned from the event() method.

```
your_variable = oo('.box').event('click', function () {});
```

You could do:

```
...
callback(_this);
...
callback.call(_this);
...

oo('.box').event('click', function (self) {
  //blah
});
```